# How do I organize a sign in page for a react-native app?

Tags: react-native

I'm super new to react-native and I had more of a general question. I hope this isn't in the wrong spot.

Let's say I have a sign-in screen for my app.

I created a SignInScreen.js file. Now in this file, I have a couple of options:

1. I could just render out two text fields (for email and password)

or

2. I could create a separate SignIn component. I would render that in the SignInScreen and then in the SignIn component, I would render the two text fields for email and password.

I'm not sure what is considered best practices. Am I over-thinking this? Would I be over engineering if I created the separate SignIn component?

Thanks so much.

Comment: You are over thinking it. It is just couple of TextInput components. Just render them inside your SignInScreen. More code means more bugs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a personal question and you are going to get mixed answers.

I would think long term. Are you going to make this only for this app? Or are you planning on re using that? If the first one, then just add the TextInput and that's it.

If you think that you might re use the code in other apps you could create a SignIn component like you said and create a module to import.

But if you are very new to RN don't complicate yourself right now.